# Failed to load application

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


@Configuration
public class WebDriverLibrary {

//    @Value("${remote.url}")
//    public URL remoteUrl;

    @Bean
    public WebDriver getRemoteWebDriverForChrome() throws MalformedURLException {
//        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
//        return new RemoteWebDriver(remoteUrl, DesiredCapabilities.chrome());

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setCapability("browserVersion", "74");
        chromeOptions.setCapability("platformName", "Windows 10");
        return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);

    }

}
```

I am getting the following error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'landingPage': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webDriver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getRemoteWebDriverForChrome' defined in class path resource [com/ksupwlt/stepcounttracker/libraries/WebDriverLibrary.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'getRemoteWebDriverForChrome' threw exception; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-55B4PJT', ip: '192.168.1.66'
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following line of code to launch the browser:

```
@Bean
    public WebDriver getChromeDriver(){
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
```

Selenium dependency version :4.1.2
selenium-http-jdk-client version: 4.5.0
It worked for me. I hope it will be useful for someone.